# Drawing UI text on GUI.DrawTexture , How to do it?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am building a bar code scanner , and needs to show the barcode data on GUI.DrawTexture

the code is :

```
 GUI.depth = 100; //this method is not working 
         GUI.DrawTexture(screenRect, camTexture, ScaleMode.ScaleToFit); // {draws the camera screen on screen  .I am using camTextue to used zxing ( barcode scanner library ) to get the barcode data , so needed it  }
```

Now i want to use UI text compponent to show on it . I have tried Z axis method or GUI.Depth method nothing is working . Always the GUI.DrawTexture is above the text .

Please anyone know how to do it .

Comment: is there a reason to use GUI class? It's now full on depreciated

Comment: Stop using OnGui and use [the new UI](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui) instead.